# How to flag salesforce records on fetching?

Tags: salesforce

I am going to pull data in batches per day using soap api, i need a flag to identify which records have been pulled the previous day so that next I don't end up pulling same records. how do I implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the id of each record you've pulled, then you only those records with id that you don't know about

Comment: agreed, but how to do that? using `exclude` SOQL query?